# Screen keeps freezing up, but unfreezes when I move the cursor

Tags: freeze

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu Budgie and I have the recurring issue where the screen will freeze up, but once I move the mouse it unfreezes. For example when I'm watching a movie, just after about 5 minutes the screen will freeze up but the audio still plays, so I have to move the cursor to unfreeze the screen. It also happens when I load up a webpage sometimes. The page will begin to load, but the page will stay white and look like it's still loading, but when I just move the cursor it will come up. Kind of hard to explain. It is super annoying though because it just keeps happening and I have to wiggle the mouse every 5 minutes when watching a movie. Any suggestions?